# Is MySQL fast enough to read from the database every time or should I cache the results?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm in the planning stage of building a web app for a school. I'm worried about the speed and efficiency of MySQL when multiple people are accessing it. The app will allow teachers to CRUD student records. Is it better to cache a `json/xml` result when a record is created/updated so that the app can quickly display it to the user (using javascript)? Or is MySQL fast enough to handle a updates and queries for the same data?

Comment: MySQL is a capable enough Database product to handle thousands of connections at the same time. I'd be more worried about the hardware than the DB engine itself.

Comment: @Icarus I'm thinking it'd be better to host this on Heroku or something simular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a program that does exactly this (plus more).  Use a database, they're designed for these queries.  Currently I've hit just under 100 concurrent users, and have a few thousand students, and have had no latency issues.

It's better, faster, safer to use a database.

Comment: +1 And most of all: it is simpler. If ever you have a problem, look at your queries and optimize them (easy). Then optimize your code (may not be as easy). Then if that's not enough (and you have thousands of ppl on your app) use a cache.

Comment: awesome. that's exactly what i was hoping for. thanks dude. @Matthieu that was gonna be next question (caching results)

Comment: You can also look into query caching along with page caching.

Answer (score 2):

JSON and XML is used for data exchanging between different platform/software. Like between PHP and Java or between twitter and C. Its good when you dont have any protocol defined and you use a common format like xml, json, yml. But if you have a protocol defined (between mysql and php) use that. That'll be much much faster. Besides as a database mysql can perform many other extra data manipulation operation that you can not achieve with plain xml or json or yml. So use mysql.

> is mysql fast enough to handle a large number of queries that will just be retrieving data to display?

Its a lot faster. I doubt whether you'll face its slowness. I have seen many devices (not human) manipulating mysql concurrently. It produces tremendous load. And mysql still handling those data.